# Plotting is taking time after taking groupby and mean

Tags: python, matplotlib, dask, python-xarray

I have xarray with coordinates:

```
1. lat(192, )
2. lon(288,0)
3. plev(10,)
4. time(14400,)

And following data variables:
1. zg(time, plev, lat, lon)
2. tas(time, lat, lon)
```

Now I'm doing groupby(monthly) and getting mean for month like this for 1 plev in zag.

```
df.groupby('time.month').mean()
```

Now when I try to plot **zg** for 1 month like this:

```
monthly_mean.zg.sel(month = 1).squeeze().plot(figsize = (10,5))
```

It's taking lot of time to plot this(Around 15 mins).

I'm not sure why this problem is happening.
Whereas I'm able to plot monthly **tas** in seconds. And even for **zg** if I plot for particular date before doing mean it's not taking time.

I'm not able to figure out where's the problem. Can someone tell me what is missing.

P.S: If someone wants I can provide the sample data.

Comment: I guess the command `.sel(month = 1).squeeze()` takes the time to plot. Please profile your code or you seperate  `monthly_mean.zg.sel(month = 1).squeeze()` into a variable and plot this result. It is also possible that there is a bug using the sel command in combination with plot.

Comment: @dl.meteo  I don't think .sel() is giving any problem cause before doing groupby when i used .sel() and gave single date inside it was plotting quickly. And there is no problem with groupby also cause after doing groupby I'm able to plot temperature quickly only zg is taking time. And my almost whole code is there, I have just opened file before that. And I tried storing monthly_mean.zg.sel(month = 1).squeeze() in some variable and then plot it, still it's the same.

Comment: I think it has something to do that you are working wih 3d data on `zg`. I think you should select one `plev` and plot them.

Comment: @dl.meteo yes I'm selecting just one value from plev, I have mentioned that above in ques, I don't know what is going wrong lol

Comment: Would be good if you can share the whole code with all outputs. And I would suggest to make an issue in the github project of xarray.

Comment: Please provide a snippet showing what happens when you print `zg` and `tas`. Are you loading this data in lazily? If so, it might be taking a while to load `zg` data into the memory when you call `.plot()` on it?